# How to perform an action every 5 results?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, logic

How can I perform an action within a `for` loop every 5 results?

Basically I'm just trying to emulate a table with 5 columns.

Answer (score 50):

you could use the modulus operator

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    if(i % 5 == 0)
    {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: If the circumstances permit you can also just use `for ($i  = 0; $i < 500; $i += 5) { ... }`.

Comment: @Johannes I think he wants to do processing for every whole number from 0 to n, but fire an action for every 5th element. I could be mistaken, though.

Comment: Note that `(i%5==0)` will run on the first, sixth, eleventh, … passes.  Use `(i%5==4)` to trigger on the fifth, tenth, fifteenth, … passes instead.

Comment: For the sake of clarity this is one of those times the loop should start at 1 as the index because using 0 makes it not as clear.

Answer (score 2):

For an HTML table, try this.

```
<?php
$start = 0;
$end = 22;
$split = 5;
?>
<table>
    <tr>
  <?php for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++) { ?>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;" >
         <?= $i; ?>
    </td>
    <?php if(($i) % ($split) == $split-1){ ?>
    </tr><tr>
    <?php }} ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: $count should be renamed.  The name "count" suggests that you would get that many cells.  If $start isn't set to zero, you won't get a number of cells equal to $count.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a condition with a modulus, as pointed out. You can also do it with nesting loops.

```
int n = 500;
int i = 0;

int limit = n - 5
(while i < limit)
{
   int innerLimit = i + 5
   while(i < innerLimit)
   {
       //loop body
       ++i;
   }
   //Fire an action
}
```

This works well if n is guaranteed to be a multiple of 5, or if you don't care about firing an extra event at the end. Otherwise you have to add this to the end, and it makes it less pretty.

```
//If n is not guaranteed to be a multiple of 5.
while(i < n)
{
  //loop body
  ++i;
}
```

and change int limit = n - 5 to int limit = n - 5 - (n % 5)

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
int j=0;
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) 
{ 
    j++;
    if(j >= 5) 
    { 
        j = 0;
        //do your stuff here 
    } 
}
```

I'm old fashioned, I remember when division took a long time. With modern cpus it probably doesn't matter much.

Comment: isn't the if should be if(j==5) ?

Answer (score 0):

This works to get a live index within the foreach loop:

```
<?php

// Named-Index Array
$myNamedIndexArray = array('foo' => 'bar', 'go' => 'habs', 'CSGO_bestTeam' => 'fnatic', 'test' => 'one two', 'potato' => 'french fries', 'tomato' => 'ketchup', 'coffee' => 'expresso', 'window' => 'cleaner', 'truck' => 'load', 'nine' => 'neuf', 'ten' => 'dix');

// Numeric-Index Array of the Named-Index Array
$myNumIndex = array_keys($myNamedIndexArray);


foreach($myNamedIndexArray as $key => $value) {
    $index = array_search($key,$myNumIndex);

    if ($index !== false) {
        echo 'Index of key "'.$key.'" is : '.$index.PHP_EOL;

        if (($index+1) % 5 == 0) {
            echo '[index='.$index.'] stuff to be done every 5 iterations'.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// That's an easy one

for($i=10;$i<500;$i+=5)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The code in this loop will not be called in every 5th run, it will be called on each! Only your variable `$i` will be increased by 5 every run.