# PHP - Loop thru recordset and fire event each n rows

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, recordset

I'm looking for the right logic to loop thru a recordset and fire an event each n times.

Searching on Google i've found some discussion on similar situations, but it seems that solutions don't fits my needs.

I need to interface my app with a webservice that use minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4" for repeatable elements in a single call. Let's say i have a recordset of 22 rows.

I need to:

1. loop thru the recordset and populate the array $data with each row
2. on the 4th row (8th, 12th, 16th...) fire the event (call the WS with $data of 4 elements)
3. empty $data and continue with the loop till the next 4th
4. if the number of rows is not multiple of 4 i must handle the remainder and fire one last call

Using the modulus operator as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500675/for-loop-do-action-every-5-results), `if($i % 4 == 0)`,  i get the event fired each 4 rows, but 22 its not a multiple of 4 so the event is fired till the 20th row and then nothing. Maybe i need to make a division counting rows in 'excess'?

Since the recordset will be between 50 and 200 rows i think its not necessary run multiple query of 4 rows, am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
Inspired by the answers below i finally managed to get the script work as i wanted... probably its not an elegant solution but works as expected:

```
$result = $query->result(); // the recordset
$total_rows = count($result);
$interleave = 4;
$reminder = $total_rows % $interleave;
$round_rows = ($total_rows-$reminder)+1; // +1 because $i dont start at zero
$data = array();
```

Start with a initial loop ($round_rows is a multiple of 4)

```
for ($i=1; $i<$round_rows; $i++){
            $data[$i] = $result[$i];
            if ($i % $interleave == 0){
                $this->fire_event($data);
                $data = array();
            }
 }
```

Then if there is a reminder, loop thru...

```
if ($total_rows % $interleave !== 0){
            for ($i = $round_rows; $i < $total_rows + 1; $i++) {
                $data[$i] = $result[$i];
            }
            $this->fire_event($data);
}
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: You found the right way. If it's up to 22, why should it fire in 21 and 22?

Comment: If you want an "event" to fire every 4 rows, why would you want it to fire on row 22 anyway? Also, what is the event? Are you calculating something?

Comment: Why do you want it to fire on row 22?

Comment: Why would you run it on the last one if its not divisible by 4?

Comment: @R2-Bacca: Sorry, i've forgot to say that i need to fire the event even at the end of the loop. I'm going to update the question...

Comment: I had a feeling you wanted to do something like that. The answer by @Eineki below is correct. All you need to do is fire the event at the end of the loop (fully outside the loop braces `for(whatever){blah} fire_my_event();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to fire an event at the end of the recordset, just do it.

```
for($i=0 .... ) {
 // do yourcalculation
}

//fire your event for the end of the recordset
```

If you need to fire the event only when you have spare records after the last event fired then use an if

```
$interleave = 4; // or whaterver you interval you need
for($i=0 .... ) {
 // do yourcalculation
}

if (!($i % $interleave)) {
    // fire your event
}
```

The `$i` index continue to live after the end of the loop and you can leverage on this language property