# For loop inside foreach PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have a simple array, for example:

```
$array = [val-1, val-2, val-3, val-4, val-5 val-6, etc]
```

I want to pass it through foreach loop, but inside that loop I want another loop to group results by 4. That's for placing them into col-md-3 div inside a row div. Please tell me if it's possible and how to implement it.
This is what I want:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 6</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 7</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Value 8</div>
</div>
```

etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? There are numerous tutorials and documentation online for this sort of thing.

Comment: 1) It is possible. 2) Trial and error.

Comment: _“but inside that loop I want another loop to group results by 4”_ - no, you don’t want a second loop for that, because that makes no sense to begin with. You want to use the modulo operator to decide when you have to output the necessary HTML to close a row and open the next one, inside your one single loop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500675/how-to-perform-an-action-every-5-results

Comment: THe general rule on SO is that you try and code it, If your code does not do what you hoped, then and only then, do you ask for help

Comment: @CBroe, Thank you! That helped!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're always going to have 4 columns, you need to do some maths on your array. Something like the following should work:

```
$arr  = [ 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6', 'val7', 'val8' ];
$cols = 4;
$rows = ceil( count($arr) / $cols );

for( $r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++ )
{
    echo '<div class="row">';

    for( $c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++ )
    { 
        echo "\n\t".'<div class="col-md-'.(12 / $cols).'">'.$arr[($r * $cols) + $c].'</div>';
    }

    echo "\n".'</div>';
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">val1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">val5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val6</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val7</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">val8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just use `array_chunk` to save yourself calculating all the math.

Answer (score -1):

The one solution that I can think of is manually breaking the array into sets of four by looping. See the code below:

```
$array = ['val-1', 'val-2', 'val-3', 'val-4', 'val-5', 'val-6', 'val-7', 'val-8'];
$result = array();
$temp = array();

$i = 1;
foreach ($array as $elem) {
    array_push($temp, $elem);
    if (($i % 4) == 0) {
        array_push($result, $temp);
        $temp = array();
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This entire solution as it is can be done in one line of code: `array_chunk($array, 4);` gives the same output.